# Conflic install package solution?

Tags: centos6, packages, auditd

I need to install auditd from package because my CentOS 6.6 server can't use yum update. But I got some problem and can't install them:

```
rpm -i audit-libs-2.4.5-6.el6.i686.rpm audit-2.4.5-6.el6.i686.rpm
warning: audit-libs-2.4.5-6.el6.i686.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID c105b9de: NOKEY
        file /lib/libaudit.so.1.0.0 from install of audit-libs-2.4.5-6.el6.i686 conflicts with file from package audit-libs-2.3.7-5.el6.i686
        file /lib/libauparse.so.0.0.0 from install of audit-libs-2.4.5-6.el6.i686 conflicts with file from package audit-libs-2.3.7-5.el6.i686
```

Any solution to install those package without any conflic?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I use:

```
rpm -Uvh <package>.rpm
```

to upgrade my pkg without problem